# Using C# I cannot sendKeys to an angular tag <app-currency-input> I get this error Element <app-currency-input class= is not reachable by keyboard'

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, selenium

I have tried a bunch of solutions like implicit wait - this does not work, the text field is clickable by mouse but unreachable by keyboard, so values cannot be inputted but text field this can be clicked.

I also have this solution

```
             IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
             IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("InvoiceAmount"));
             js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='100';", element);
```

this does nothing and does not give any error also. Please help. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Can you share the HTML in text format here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bcz of that you found wrong element. You found `<app-currency-input>`. But you have to get a nested input (native `<input>` element).

Try this:

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("InvoiceAmount"));
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> inputElements = element.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='100';", inputElements[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find element and click before sending keys?

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("InvoiceAmount"));
Action.MoveToElement(element,0,0).Click().Build().Perform();
```